# JetBrains Idea Custom Ligatures

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, phpstorm, ligature

I have managed to create a few ligatures in some font editing software such as birdfont.  However after I have installed my font into windows and I load PhpStorm, I select my font with the ligatures I have created but PhpStorm can't seem to display them.

My question is, can I make ligatures for letter sequences like `f u n c t i o n` or `c l a s s` for example? These are non standard ligatures that don't come included with FiraCode but I would really like to be able to make ligatures for these sequences, I have made them externally but how do I get PhpStorm or any JetBrains software to recognize them?

Comment: For example FiraCode has ligatures for -> and !== for example, I dont know if this is somehow hard coded into phpstorm to replace these with ligature characters or if thats somehow built into the font itself, even though my ligature program didnt seem to work

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes!  You can make extra ligatures inside of a font and jetbrains will render them without any extra configuration.  See the response from Nikita Prokopov below.

https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/341

I believe it requires using a font editor like Glyphs.app or FontForge for example, so you should be able to configure a ligature character sequence in the font and the corresponding character/glyph in the font and jetbrains will be able to support it out of the box.