# Is there a way to support custom ligatures in Pycharm?

Tags: fonts, pycharm, latex, customization, ligature

I know how to enable font ligatures, but I want there to be many more.
For example, I would replace "in" with "∈", "not in" with "∉", "set()" with "∅", and more complex but still something I would like to do: replace "`sum(x[i] for i in range(1,n))`" with: [image: in case the image doesn't show up: lyx: \sum_{i=1}^n x_i]

So in general, I want to replace common programming writing with the respective common mathematical writing.

I'm pretty sure there isn't anything "out of the box" for this, so if you can give me details on how to add these things to a font, it would be amazing.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41302538/13576700

Comment: This will be useful for sure. It doesn't resolve it fully, but it'll help :)